# Max size of Object

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to download table data of a webpage but it looks like that the webpage is too big.

If I put the ".response" data in a "String"-variable, and save it to a textfile, I'll get all the data what is on the webpage. If I do this after saving it to an "HTMLDocument"-variable I only get the first 51594 characters

This is my script:

```
Sub nemigaparts_articles()

Dim oHtml As HTMLDocument
Dim oElement As Object
Dim URL As String
Dim id As String

Dim z As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim row As Long
Dim totaal As Long
Dim begin As Long

'data for save as
Dim start As Long
Dim eind As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

begin = 1
totaal = 2
row = 1


start = 1
eind = 0

'laat statusbalk zien
UserForm1.Show

For z = begin To totaal Step 1

    'get page data
    'URL = Sheets("drawings").Cells(z, 3).Value
    'id = Sheets("drawings").Cells(z, 1).Value
    URL = "https://nemigaparts.com/cat_spares/pet/porsche/964/13/902000/"
    id = 1
    Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", LCase(URL), False
        .send
        oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Sheets("articles").Cells(1, 11) = z


    Dim imageurl As Object
    Set imageurl = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 xs-margin-bottom-50")(0)
    URL_img = imageurl.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href



    Dim atribuut As Object
    Set atribuut = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("technical")(0)
    If Not atribuut Is Nothing Then
    x = oHtml.getElementsByTagName("tr").Length - 1
    MsgBox (x)
        For y = 1 To x Step 1
            Sheets("articles").Cells(row, 1) = id
            Sheets("articles").Cells(row, 2) = URL_img
            Sheets("articles").Cells(row, 3) = oHtml.getElementsByTagName("tr")(y).innerHTML
            row = row + 1
        Next
    End If
    DoEvents
    UserForm1.Label2.Width = (z / totaal * 100) / 100 * 186
    UserForm1.Label4.Caption = "Artikel " & z & " van " & totaal
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What specifically do you want from that page?

Comment: Excuse me for being unclear, I want all the table rows, I'm doing that by using "getElementsByTagName("tr")(y)"